# How do I pass a DynamoDB table address and Redis port and address to my EC2 instance in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have a system that requires an EC2 instance that has connections to a DynamoDB table and a Redis instance.  How do I set those up as options for my EC2 instance in CloudFormation using YAML?

I've created OptionSettings to set the values as environmental variable for my process on the EC2 instance. I know that I need to do !Ref [something here], but the documentation did not have examples that made sense to me.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Description: CloudFormation template

Resources:
  # Beanstalk application
  MyApp:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
  ConfigurationTemplate:
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref MyApp
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: REDIS_CACHE_PORT
        Value: !Ref AttributeCache.Port # Should be 6379
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: REDIS_CACHE_ADDRESS
        Value: !Ref MyCache. # Something that AWS creates
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: DYNAMODB_TABLE_ADDRESS
        Value: !Ref MyDynamoTable. # Something that AWS creates
      SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2018.03 v4.8.1 running Node.js

  # Redis cache
  MyCache:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: MyCacheCluster
      Engine: redis
      EngineVersion: 4.0.10
      NumCacheNodes: 1
      Port: 6379

  # DynamoDB table
  MyDynamoTable:
    Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: theAttributeName
        AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: theAttributeName
        KeyType: HASH
      TableName: myDynamoTable
```

I am unsure of how to access something that CloudFormation will create.
Is !Ref correct, or do I need the !GetAtt instead?

Here are the links to the two different function docs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

Even just pointing me at the thing that I'm missing would be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of information is specified under [Return Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster-ref) section in the documentation for every service. This doc section also provides information whether you have to use `!Ref` or `!GetAtt` in order to retrieve certain parameter. For example [CacheCluster docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster-ref) say that you have to use `!GetAtt MyCache.RedisEndpoint.Port` to get redis' port and [Dynamo docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#w2ab1c21c10c97c14c15) say that you have to use `!Ref MyDynamoTable` to get table name.

```yaml
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: REDIS_CACHE_PORT
        Value: !GetAtt MyCache.RedisEndpoint.Port
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: REDIS_CACHE_ADDRESS
        Value: !GetAtt MyCache.RedisEndpoint.Address
      - Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: DYNAMODB_TABLE_ADDRESS
        Value: !Ref MyDynamoTable # You got this one right, but no dot in the end
```